# How to configure Windows to allow Golang app to trust CA of self-signed cert

Tags: go, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have a 3rd party development tool that was written in Golang. My company uses Netskope which injects self-signed certificates in any SSL traffic from my machine so they can monitor all traffic for security purposes. The application is failing with the error
"self signed certificate in certificate chain" when it tries to connect out to a site on the public internet, I assume because of these self-signed certificates in the chain

I found some comments that say the logic for certification verification on Windows can be found in https://go.dev/src/crypto/x509/root_windows.go, but I cannot find any documentation for Windows about this (only Linux). From looking at that code, my understanding is I need to have the CA certification set up in the local machine store as a Trusted Root CA but that isn't working for me. The screenshot here shows the CA certificates in my Local Machine trusted root CA store. I deploy to Linux containers, in JVM or other applications to allow them to trust these self-signed certificates.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong in setting up the CA certs in my Certificate Store? Is there any documentation on this? Is there another way I can configure on Windows any Golang application running on my machine to trust the CA for these self-signed certificates? I see on Linux you can similarly add the CA to your store, or use environment variables `SSL_CERT_FILE` and `SSL_CERT_DIR`, and I've been able to do this for other Golang applications in Linux containers.